# JavaScript OOP wrong _this value

Tags: javascript, oop, this, self

Let's assume we have the following code:

```
var MyClass = (function(){
    var _this;

    function MyClass(inputVal){
        _this = this;
        this.value = inputVal;
    }

    MyClass.prototype.getValue = function(){
        return this.value;
    }

    MyClass.prototype.getValue2 = function(){
        return _this.value;
    }

    return MyClass;
})();
```

Let's make two instances of the class:

```
var instance1 = new MyClass(10);
var instance2 = new MyClass(20);
```

Now if we console.log() the values we see that:

```
instance1.getValue();   // 10
instance1.getValue2();  // 20
```

```js
var MyClass = (function(){
    var _this;

    function MyClass(inputVal){
        _this = this;
        this.value = inputVal;
    }

    MyClass.prototype.getValue = function(){
        return this.value;
    }

    MyClass.prototype.getValue2 = function(){
        return _this.value;
    }

    return MyClass;
})();


var instance1 = new MyClass(10);
var instance2 = new MyClass(20);


console.log(instance1.getValue());
console.log(instance1.getValue2());
```

Why is that happening? It looks obviously that the `_this` variable gets the latest created instance properties. How to fix that? I need to keep a copy of `this`. Thanks!

**Edit:**

Here's the real situation

```
var HoverEffects = (function(){
    var _this;

    function HoverEffects($nav){
        _this = this;
        this._$activeNav = $nav.siblings('.active_nav');
        this._$hoverableLis = $nav.find('>li');
        this._$activeLi = $nav.find('>li.active');

        if(!$nav.length || !this._$hoverableLis.length || !this._$activeNav.length || !this._$activeLi.length) return;

        if(this._$activeNav.hasClass('bottom')){
            this._$activeNav.align = 'bottom';
            this._$activeLi.cssDefault = {
                left: this._$activeLi.position().left,
                width: this._$activeLi.width()
            };
        }
        else if(this._$activeNav.hasClass('left')){
            this._$activeNav.align = 'left';
            this._$activeLi.cssDefault = {
                top: this._$activeLi.position().top,
                height: this._$activeLi.height()
            };
        }
        else{
            return;
        }

        this._$hoverableLis.hover(
            function(){

                // How to set the correct this inside this function?
                if(this._$activeNav.align === 'bottom'){
                    this._$activeNav.css({
                        left: $(this).position().left,
                        width: $(this).width()
                    });
                }
                else if(this._$activeNav.align === 'left'){
                    this._$activeNav.css({
                        top: $(this).position().top,
                        height: $(this).height()
                    });
                }

            },

            function(){
                // Same here, wrong this
                this._$activeNav.css(this._$activeLi.cssDefault);
            }
        );
    }

    return HoverEffects;
})();

var sideNavHoverMagic = new HoverEffects($('#side-navigation'));
var primaryNavHoverMagic = new HoverEffects($('#primary-navigation'));
```

Comment: "I need to keep a copy of `this`" what for exactly? What is it that you're attempting to accomplish. Prototype methods already have access to `this`. Are you attempting to pass `getValue` as a callback to another method?

Comment: @zzzzBov Because I need to call a private method from a nested function. For instance - the jquery's $('#element').hover(function(){ privateFunc.call(this); },function(){ privateFunc.call(this); }); won't work, as it is not passing the correct context, and you need _this here.

Comment: You're passing `this` incorrectly there because `this` isn't referring to the object instance you want. You'll need to show more code for me to point out your specific issue. Storing the instance *outside* the constructor is the wrong way to go about solving the problem you're having.

Comment: You have to keep a reference to `this` *where* you make the call to the jQuery function. Currently there is only a single `_this` that is shared by *all* instances. This might help: [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It just don't make sense. Please elaborate, what is your motivation. Why are u trying to magically bind `this` of two independent instances of same class? Why not just `http://jsbin.com/bokigox/edit?html,js,console`?

Comment: Please check the updated question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is that happening?

Every time you call `new MyClass`, `_this = this` gets run. The second time overrides the first time.

So `_this` refers to `new MyClass(20)`, which means that when you call `getValue2` from *any* `MyClass` instance, `20` will be returned because *all* `MyClass` instances are referring to the same `_this` value.

---

Based on commentary on the Question:

If you're attempting to pass a function bound to the appropriate context there are a variety of ways to make sure that `this` refers to the right object. Before continuing, please read ["How does the 'this' keyword work?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/497418), because there's no reason for me to repeat all of it here.

If you're binding event callbacks such as in a constructor:

```
function Example(something) {
    something.addEventListener(..event.., this.callback, false);
}
Example.prototype.callback = function () {
    this.doStuff();
    this.doMoreStuff();
};
```

The callback will have the wrong `this` value because it's not being called as `this.callback`, it's just being called as:

```
fn = this.callback;
fn(); //no reference to this
```

You can get around this in a number of ways.

### `Function.prototype.bind`

You can bind the `callback` for every instance on their respective instance. This is very concise:

```
function Example(something) {
    //generate a new callback function for each instance that will
    //always use its respective instance
    this.callback = this.callback.bind(this);
    something.addEventListener(..event.., this.callback, false);
}
Example.prototype.callback = function () {
    this.doStuff();
    this.doMoreStuff();
};
```

### `that = this`

You can create the callback (closure) *within* the constructor and reference a variable inside the constructor.

```
function Example(something) {
    //every Example object has its own internal "that" object
    var that = this;
    this.callback = function () {
        //this function closes over "that"
        //every instance will have its own function rather than
        //a shared prototype function.
        that.doStuff();
        that.doMoreStuff();
    }

    something.addEventListener(..event.., this.callback, false);
}
```

### `() => {}` ([Fat Arrow Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Arrow_functions))

If you're using ES2015 you can use "fat arrow" syntax for creating lambdas that don't create a new context:

```
function Example(something) {
    this.callback = () => {
        //the callback function doesn't create a new "this" context
        //so it referes to the "this" value from "Example"
        //every instance will have its own function rather than
        //a shared prototype function.
        that.doStuff();
        that.doMoreStuff();
    }

    something.addEventListener(..event.., this.callback, false);
}
```

Comment: `The second time overrides the first time.` I don't think `var instance2 = new MyClass(20);` would override `var instance1 = new MyClass(10);`. They are 2 difference instances.

Comment: @TânNguyễn: `MyClass` gets called twice, the second call assigns a new value to `_this` (the value is *overwritten*).

Comment: @TânNguyễn, I never said that `instance2` overrides `instance1`. I said that `_this = this` will be called every time the constructor is executed, which is where the issue comes from.

Comment: @zzzzBov How to keep a correct _this value? Is there anything wrong with the pattern I used?